# How do I customize view templates in ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

When I add a new strongly-typed view in VStudio 2010, I get fields layed out like this.

```
<div class="display-label">Id</div>
<div class="display-field"><%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %></div>
```

In 2008, it used to use p tags instead of all these divs, my css is set up to handle the p tags properly, but since upgrading I have these now, so I have to spend time editing by hand removing the divs and adding p tags. (Plus, I just like the idea of using logical p tags instead of this mess.)

Is there a way I can modify the template?

Comment: semantically speaking, div tags are more appropriate for fields than p tags.  p tags semantically refer to paragraphs, divs to "divisions" Your label is not a seperate paragraph from your data field.

Comment: I use it more like this <p>Id: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %></p> So each field is a paragraph tag.

Comment: That's still not semantically correct, each row of your form data is not its own paragraph.  Semantically speaking, you should wrap your form in one or more Fieldsets with optional captions, and use divs between them.  Screen readers ignore divs, while a screen reader will anounce each row as a new paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  [This if for MVC3 but I believe it is very similar if not the same for MVC2.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

You can also override the templates by creating your own display templates.  [Brad Wilson shows this...](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)  [and one more....](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/)